# pipをアップデートできない。

Tags: python, python3, anaconda, pip

pythonのpipを更新しようとすると、エラーが発生します。そのため、pipを更新することができません。

Anacondaでcondaとpipを実行していたため、それによりファイルが壊れたかと思い、Anacondaをアンインストールしましたが、解決できませんでした。

ちなみに、 `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` をコマンドプロンプトで実行すると、

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

'c:\\users\\user名\\appdata\\roaming\\python\\python37\\site-packages\\pip-19.0.1.dist-info\\METADATA'
```

というようなエラーが発生します。

これをどうしたら解決でき、pipを更新できるでしょうか。どなたか分かる人は、お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Anacondaでは `pip` ではなく `conda` を使う必要があります。今回はアンインストールしてしまったとのことですので、一旦Anacondaを再インストールしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

参考：[condaとpip：混ぜるな危険 - onoz000’s blog](http://onoz000.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/02/11/142347)

また、どうしても `pip` を直接使う必要がある場合は、 `venv` やAnaconda内のターミナルを使う方法が本家SOに示されています（今回の質問の本筋とは離れるので、紹介までに留めておきます）。
[python - Using Pip to install packages to Anaconda Environment - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060382/using-pip-to-install-packages-to-anaconda-environment)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。付け加えですが、こちらはコマンドプロンプトで行った結果がこのようになりました。

Comment: これは、アンインストールしたAnacondaのファイルがまだ残っているということでしょうか。

Comment: その可能性は大いにあります（Anacondaは便利ですが、システム標準の環境を壊すことも多いです）。再インストールして確認はされましたか？

Comment: まだ、試しておりませんので近い内にまたやってみようと思います。けれども、一つ気になることがあります。それは、Anacondaを再インストールをしてcondaで実行できるようになったら、pipも復活するのかといった疑問です。

Comment: なぜ `pip` を使う必要があるのでしょうか？基本的に、Anacondaをインストールした時点で標準の環境をそのまま使うのは面倒になるため、 `conda` を代わりに使うほうがよろしいかと思うのですが。

Comment: 了解しました。ありがとうございます。